# "you are in emergency mode,, After logging in type "journalctl -xb"ti view..."

Tags: ubuntu, interfaz-gráfica, ram, boot

Estuve lanzando un programa el cual excedió la RAM de mi pc, (sistema operativo pop os (basado en ubuntu), luego de reiniciar, mi GUI no aparece (solo interfaz de linea de comandos) y me aparece el mensaje del titulo:

> "you are in emergency mode,, After logging in type "journalctl -xb"ti
> view...".

Ante esto tipeo: `sudo gedit -H /etc/fstab` como se recomienda aca: https://askubuntu.com/questions/960790/stuck-in-emergency-mode-and-nothing-works

Al ejecutar dicho comando obtengo lo siguiente:

> unable to init server: no se pudo encontrar. Conexión rehusada

Intenté instalando gedit con `sudo apt-get install gedit-common` pero el paquete ya esta instalado.

Al correr `sudo apt-get upgrade` obtengo

> Fallo al obtener : https//us.archive.ubuntu.....

Tengo una tarjeta grafica nvidia, no se si tenga que ver algo al respecto, no he actualizado el sistema en dos meses por unos errores que obtenía de actualizaciones mas recientes.

Comment: Si no tienes GUI, no hay forma de usar gedit. Intenta editar /etc/fstab usando vi o nano (con sudo). Igual, ten cuidado con lo que cambias: revisa y compara la salida de blkid y el contenido de ese archivo como lo indica [esta respuesta](https://askubuntu.com/a/1141854) a esa pregunta que citas.

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: tu problema esta relacionada al manejo de aplicaciones en el sistema operativo, y no a algo relacionado a los objetivos del sitio (Desarrollo y programación).